# JavaScript/Hightables - Add unique items with time and output percentage

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a pie chart with Hightables to show a breakdown of tasks and time spent on them.

Currently I have a HTML table with information as below:

```
Task Description    Time Taken
Working on ticket   235
Proactive Maintenance   1127
Documentation   1797
Working on ticket   571
Proactive Maintenance   1161
Administration Task 785
Proactive Maintenance   217
Administration Task 831
Proactive Maintenance   1679
```

My chart gets the data correctly but shows each line as a piece of the pie, but I want it all added up.

Below is my chart code:

```
Highcharts.chart('tablecontainer', {
  data: {
    table: 'datatable'
  },
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Time Breakdown'
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
});
```

Here is what the chart ends up looking like:

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjOYC.png)
Can anyone suggest the best way to group these and show them in one piece of the pie?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Considering your data looks like this, which is the format the pie chart expects

```
var data = [{name:"Working on ticket", y: 235},
{name:"Proactive Maintenance", y:   1127},
{name:"Documentation", y:   1797},
{name:"Working on ticket", y:   571},
{name:"Proactive Maintenance", y:   1161},
{name:"Administration Task", y: 785},
{name:"Proactive Maintenance", y:   217},
{name:"Administration Task", y: 831},
{name:"Proactive Maintenance", y:   1679}];
```

you could group it yourself

```
var grouppedData = new Array();
for (var i in data)
{
    if (grouppedData[data[i].name] == undefined)
    {
          grouppedData[data[i].name] = data[i].y
    }
    else
    {
            grouppedData[data[i].name] += data[i].y
    }
}
data = new Array();
for (var i in grouppedData)
{
     data.push({ name: i, y: grouppedData[i]});
}
```

Here is the full fiddle with the chart generated http://jsfiddle.net/caqenfv4/